# Can I say the f(x) = 5x + 2 is bijective?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I would like to know if I understood this correctly. Let's say that we have the function

F: R -> Z

f(x) = 5x + 2

is this function bijective?

Bijective = injective + surjective

1. Is this function injective? I think yes because there is no two different `x` that will give us the same function output.
2. Is this function surjective, I think yes because

f(x) = y

-> 5x + 2 = y

-> ${x = \frac {y - 2}{5}}$

So,  ${\forall y \in Z}$ we will have that ${x \in R}$

It is means that this function is bijective, right?

Comment: What is $R{{}}$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, given that it's going to '$Z$', it's probably reals to integers (since there's no other LaTeX).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that this function isn't well-defined, as not all real inputs into $f$ yield an integer output. If it were instead defined as $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, then this would be fine.

---

Yes, you can say that.

Proof of injectivity:

Suppose $f(a) = f(b)$. Then $5a + 2 = 5b + 2$, so $5a = 5b$. This yields $a=b$, so $f(x) = f(y)$ only if $x=y$.

Proof of surjectivity:

Note that for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $f(x) = n$, then $5x + 2 = n$, so $x = \frac{n-2}{5} \in \mathbb{R}$, so $x$ is a valid input for the function.

Thus, $f$ is both injective and surjective, so it is bijective.

Comment: This seems to grant the premise that this is a function with domain $\mathbb R$ and range $\mathbb Z,$ which is absurd. (The proof of injectivity is correct though.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yeah, it isn't a well-defined function.